# C#/.NET Unit Testing with ADO.NET and Npgsql

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, ado.net, npgsql

I want to write unit tests for my .NET app that uses ADO.NET and Npgsql - I am not using Entity Framework (for various reason, primarily I want to improve my sql). I am having trouble finding documentation on how to test my code. More specifically, on how to make a mock database that represents how I have my data access layer setup - without using EF. Do I even write unit tests for this or do I just stick to integration tests? Do I create an in memory EF database that resembles the real db? I am relatively new to unit tests so I am not entirely sure what to ask. Any and all help/advice/criticism welcome. Thanks!

My data access layer:

```
using Domain;
using Npgsql;
using Persistence.Logger;


namespace Persistence.DAL
{
  public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
  {
    IConnections _connections;

    ILogger _logger;

    public UserRepository(IConnections connections, ILogger logger)
    {
      _connections = connections;
      _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<User> GetUserById(int userId)
    {
      var user = new User();
      await using NpgsqlConnection conn = _connections.GetConnection();
      {
        try
        {
          if (conn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) { await conn.OpenAsync(); }
          var sqlString = $"SELECT * FROM get_user_by_id({userId})";
          await using NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sqlString, conn);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", userId);

          await using var rdr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();

          if (await rdr.ReadAsync())
          {
            user = new User(rdr);
            return user;
          }
          {
            // No user found for the given ID
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid user ID.");
          }
        }
        catch (NpgsqlException ex)
        {
          // Handle PostgreSQL-specific exceptions
          await _logger.Log(ex);
          throw; // Re-throw the exception to propagate it further
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          // Handle general exceptions
          await _logger.Log(ex);
          throw new Exception("An error occurred while fetching the user.");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Logger.cs:

```
    using Persistence.DAL;

namespace Persistence.Logger
{
  public class Logger : ILogger
  {

    private IDataLogger _dataLogger;

    public Logger(IDataLogger dataLogger)
    {
      _dataLogger = dataLogger;
    }

    public async Task Log(Exception exception)
    {
      await _dataLogger.LogError(exception);
    }

    public async Task Log(Exception exception, string userId)
    {
      await _dataLogger.LogError(exception, userId);
    }
  }
}
```

Connections.cs:

```
using Npgsql;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace Persistence.DAL
{
  public class Connections : IConnections
  {
    private IConfiguration _config;
    public Connections(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
      _config = configuration;
    }

    public NpgsqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
      return new NpgsqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("connectionString"));
    }
  }
}
```

UserLogic.cs:

```
using Domain;
using Persistence.DAL;

namespace Persistence.BLL
{
  public class UserLogic : IUserLogic
  {
    private readonly IUserRepository _repository;
    public UserLogic(IUserRepository repository)
    {
      _repository = repository;

    }

    public Task<User> GetUserById(int userId)
    {
      return _repository.GetUserById(userId);
    }

  }
}
```

User model:

```
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Domain
{
  public class User
  {
    public User() { }
    public User(DbDataReader rdr)
    {
      this.Id = Int32.Parse(rdr["id"].ToString());
      this.UserName = rdr["user_name"].ToString();
      this.Created = DateTime.Parse(rdr["created"].ToString(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Comment: The "how thoroughly i should test" can't be answered that is something you need to come up yourself. The word "unit" implies that something can be tested with dependencies under control to test only this "unit". You can't really test error behavior repeatable if you use Npgsql stuff directly in your repository. You want be able to provoke errors easily (like timeouts, deadlocks, conflicts etc) in tests. Try to program against the base classes of those classes  (DBConnection or even IDbConnection etc.)  and not the concrete classes so they get exchangeable and you can control there behavior.

Comment: This `new User(rdr);` looks also like a problem to me. You transport a npgsql dependency out of your repository even if not surfaced later by that class. Try the needed mapping you do now in the ctor in the repository itself to get rid of that dependency.

Comment: @Ralf not sure if i follow. What do you mean by "in the ctor in the repository itself". Do you mean just add a mapping method within UserRepository.cs? I added my User.cs class to show what the mapping looks like.

Answer (score 1):

For end-to-end (integration) testing, you need to test against a real PostgreSQL database with sample data; this gives you confidence that your application is working end-to-end, and is generally required for any sort of serious application. It's very easy to spin up a PostgreSQL instance for your tests (e.g. [see testcontainers](https://dotnet.testcontainers.org/modules/postgres/)); you'll have to think about test isolation (so that multiple concurrent tests don't interfere which either other), but that shouldn't be a problem.

Then, if you want unit testing which doesn't involve your real database, exclude Npgsql out of your tests entirely. Build a data API over it (a repository) which you can then mock in your tests to return exactly the data you want to the component you're testing.

Comment: Any links please?